# Google Cloud Container-vm does not restart docker containers

Tags: docker, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

We have a machine using a container-vm. The containers are configured to have a restart policy of "always". It means that when the docker daemon is restarted (or the machine rebooted) the containers will be restarted.

This feature works perfectly on my development environment but not on a container-vm image.

You can reproduce this issue by:
1. Create a vm from a container-vm image

```
$ gcloud compute instances create boat --project "databerries" --image container-vm --zone europe-west1-d --machine-type f1-micro
```

2. Create a container (nginx as example)

   $ sudo su

   ## docker run --name some-nginx --restart=always -d nginx
3. Check that the container is launched

   ## docker ps

   CONTAINER ID IMAGE COMMAND CREATED STATUS PORTS NAMES
   7b616d41ba9b nginx:latest "nginx -g 'daemon of 4 seconds ago Up 4 seconds 80/tcp, 443/tcp some-nginx
4. Restart the docker deamon

   ## service docker restart
5. Check if the container is launched

   ## docker ps -a

   CONTAINER ID IMAGE COMMAND CREATED STATUS PORTS NAMES
   7b616d41ba9b nginx:latest "nginx -g 'daemon of About a minute ago Exited (0) 22 seconds ago some-nginx

The container is not restarted.

Comment: Have you considered using CoreOS? I just tried it on Compute Engine with --restart=always and it worked fine.

Comment: It looks like you are restarting the docker service which will not necessarily restart your container. Are you expecting docker restarts to restart all containers on the machine?

Comment: @SandeepDinesh It works well on CoreOS.

Comment: @Ian Lewis I am expecting restarting the docker service or rebooting computer to restart all containers on the machine.